# Mongoose Find vs Find Where

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just started working with MongooseJS and i'm wondering which among these queries is the best way to do a find-where query. This query?

```
post.Model
            .findOne({
                _id     : id,
                creator : creator
            })
            .remove(function(err, results) {
                callback(err, results);
            });
```

or this query?

```
post.Model
                .findOne({
                    creator : creator
                })
                .where('_id')
                .equals(id)
                .remove(function(err, results) {
                    callback(err, results);
                });
```

Both works the way i want it too but I feel that i'm doing something wrong and that there is a better way to do this. I've been searching for sample queries that may help me and I found different implementations such as doing:

```
post.Model.findOne({ $where : [ ] })
```

TIA. And I apologize for the newb question.

Comment: ...and why not `.findOne().where('creator').equals(creator).where('_id').equals(id)`? confusing topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have the document's _id, then `Model.findById(_id, callback);` is the clearest way to express that query. When querying with conditions that could match multiple documents, `Model.find(queryConditions, callback);` vs. chaining style is mostly a matter of preference/style/opinion. My personal opinion is using a query object is simpler and more straightforward than chaining, which I almost never like, but again it's a style thing.

In all your examples, since you have a unique _id, there is no reason to also query on `creator`.